# Trouble compiling for iOS 11.1 with Xamarin (Visual Studio)

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin

There is not much of a point in posting actual code here, because we're talking about 7 different apps.

All of these apps have been up on the Apple Store and running fine.  Until the new iOS 11.1 came out.  Now I am being forced to update all of those apps, and rearrange the screen to allow for the new layout of the iPhone X.

Now all of this seems mostly reasonable, if not ridiculous for them changing their own design standard.  But the real problem is that I went through all of that.  Upgraded Xamarin (Visual Studio), and packages, and Xcode, and the Simulators, AND my Mac system.  Everything is up to speed.  The apps **compile and test fine** on any simulator I install them on.

The only change to the code is moving stuff around on the screen.  Well, that, and I now need to drop support for anything i386.  It all has to be x86_64 now.

From what I can tell, that is a difference from 32-bit to 64-bit.  And that change is a dropdown menu choice in the Project Options.  In any case, there is no indication at all that there is anything wrong with these apps at all.

So with all of this, I submit my apps for approval, and every single one of them gets rejected because "The app crashes on startup."  And they kindly attach a log file showing what went wrong.

Now, I know I can simply scour those logs, for all 7 apps... The log files need to be fed into some other program that can decipher them, because they are not human-readable.  Which is just annoying...

What I'm hoping is that someone can save me some trouble and explain what they changed in their systems that is not being caught by the compilers or the simulators.

Any help would be hot.

Comment: Are you testing on physical devices?

Comment: First of all, I get really annoyed with how quick people are to downvote.  You'd think I never helped anyone here before.  Sheesh...  Anyway...  No, I am not testing on devices.  I cannot afford to buy a new iPhone every time one comes out.  And testing on physical devices is ridiculously difficult anyway, unless you can get a bunch of people on TestFlight.

Comment: There are Mobile Testing Clouds such as Azure App Center Test : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/

Comment: Ok, but if all they are going to tell me is that the app crashes, and provide a log file, that still doesn't help.  I am actively searching Xamarin's forums to see what they have to say.  I will update this question with an answer, assuming I find one.  Whether downvoted or not, I'm going to assume that I'm not the only developer in the universe with this problem.

Comment: Apple's iOS simulators are just that "simulators", they do not provide an exact runtime "emulation" of the physical devices. As to why your apps are faulting under iOS11 could be related to a number of things that changed in iOS 11 (like permissions), symbolizing the iOS crash logs that Apple provides would be a start to understanding your app's problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my own answer because I have not seen one anywhere that addresses what I have found to have worked.  So I am providing this information for the next small developer, like myself, can get some useful answers to questions where Apple and Xamarin are simply NO HELP at all.

Xamarin does provide a page that essentially says, "get your app ready for iOS 11."  The most useful part of this is where it shows you how to remove any linkage to anything 32-bit.

[Architecture changes](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios11/updating-your-app/architecture-changes/)

This is mostly helpful.  And I thought that once that was done, I'd be all set.  There are 2 other things they completely fail to mention:
- You must set your target device to 11.1.  You cannot have it set for 9.0.  That will make the app crash on an 11.1 system.
- You must make a change in the manual code editing (source) section of the info.plst file.  Why this is not done automatically, I cannot say.  You must add an entry to the "Required Device Capabilities" section for "arm64".  You also must remove the one for arm7.

Failure to do these two things, even after making their suggested changes will cause the app to crash on iOS 11.1 devices.

If you think I'm having a bit of an attitude problem about this, yes, I am.  And I will not apologize for it.

It is absurd for Apple to change their design specs, give us very little time to make changes, and then not provide the absolutely essential information to actually make the changes.  I blame Xamarin too.  For the exact same reasons.

It is also absurd to totally deprecate all the testing devices I have, and then ask, "why don't you test on an actual device?"  Because I cannot afford a new $1000 phone for the sake of testing apps that barely make me any money anyway.  That's why.

And people wonder why I think it's a pain in the bum to develop for iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

1) Some of the frameworks that your app use may use libraries, that does not work correctly on iPhone. The reason for that is that when you compile your project on the simulator, is still compile it for a PC architecture, not a mobile one. And if there are any differences, only a real device could tell you about them.

2) I would suggest you to use this method to symbolicate crash reports from Apple. That at least should give you some clue. In summary, what you need to do is after you compile your app, you need to save a few files (.dSYM and .ipa) Then when apple send you back a report, you would be able to symbolicate it into human readable. You can find more info on how to do it here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/symbolicate-ios-crash/

Comment: You would be correct about the libraries.  But that is actually not the problem.  I have updated everything, including the simulators, packages...  Everything.  I appreciate the tip on the crash reports.  But what I would really love to know is, where is the logic in providing crash reports that are SO difficult to read?!  Don't tell me it's "for security".  That's nonsense.  And, yes, I am REALLY pissed off because of the lack of useful information about this.  Makes me feel like Apple Development must remain arcane and privileged except to the elite.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I can feel you pain bro.. But it's not about security. The thing is that you upload a release build, from which all debug information is stripped. Even if Apple wants, they cant provide you with a readable crashlog, since they does not have a method map to memory. It's generated once on build, and it's unique for each build. So you need to map it back on your side.

Comment: I still see no logic to it.  What I also see no logic to is that after generating these encrypted logs, they provide NO useful information how to read them.  There are a couple of ideas here, others I've found elsewhere.  I have still had exactly zero success.  Every single instruction set has information that simply does not match ANYTHING on my side.  Those menus don't exist in XCode, that file is not there, that path doesn't exist, you name it.  It's a crap system.  One that should have been fixed LONG before I started complaining.

Comment: @durbnpoisn They are not 'encrypted' in any way. They just not connected with debug information. The thing is that as I remember if you upload archive with your app via XCode, .dSYM file will be added automatically. So that's more Visual Studio (Xamarin) problem, rather than Apple. Please, follow the instructions at the link that I posted in my question, it's not so hards as it may seem. But you may have to submit your apps one more time, so you would have a valid .dSYM files.

Comment: I did try that.  "/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/" does not exist on my Mac.  I can see as far as Caches.  Nothing else matches.  In short, I could find no dSym file anywhere.  And this is the sort of thing I'm talking about.  Why on Earth don't they just make "read crash logs" an option in Xcode?  Why do I have to jump through hoops?  Where is the logic in that?!

Comment: Then try "Project Directory" -> iOS Project -> bin -> iPhone ->  Release. There should be .dSYM file. But they are unique for each build, so you can't just take random one and pass it, you need exactly the one that was generated on the same time with your app that you submitted to Apple. Regarding that complicated process - If you develop natively with XCode, there are no such problems.